# Windows 10 There is an error with your installation. Please reinstall the application

Tags: windows-10

I'm getting the following vague error message in a popup after I reboot Windows 10. "Product update There is an error with your installation. Please reinstall the application."

How can I track down the source of this error message and fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the error message's window have anything useful in the title bar?  Often this will include the name of the application that's barking at something.  If that doesn't help, use AutoRuns to view the list of programs that load at startup and disable them one at a time to see if the error message goes away.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, the title bar of the window only contains "Product update". Task Manager for Win 10 now has a startup tab. Would AutoRuns show me something that Task Manager would not? Will AutoRuns work on Win 10?

Comment: Found the problem by clicking update application from the taskbar. Turns out it is something from http://www.paretologic.com/ that I didn't intend to install. Apparently it was stuck in a partial install. I guess I need to go ahead and install it then uninstall since it doesn't show up in the installed programs list.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem by clicking update application from the taskbar. Turns out it is something from paretologic.com that I didn't intend to install.

It was not possible to continue the install.

I searched all files & folders on C: and delete them.

Problem solved!